# How can I use ArrayDeque-like List in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, arraydeque

I currently have a use case where I need a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) data structure. The requirements are that both insertion and deletion at the head and tail need to be optimized, and the ability to optimally `get` an item at any index is also required.

I know that if I use a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), insertion and deletion at both the head and tail are `O(1)`, but the `get` operation at a specific index is `O(n)`.

On the other hand, if I use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), insertion and deletion at the head are `O(n)`.

I am aware that a circular array, [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) in Java, could fit my use case. However, `ArrayDeque` doesn't implement the `List` interface, and thus it doesn't have the `get` method.

My question:

How can I best handle this use case in Java?

Comment: It's awful that `ArrayDeque` doesn't have `get`.  I use `ArrayList` for this, keeping track of the number of unused elements at the beginning.  When that number is >= half the list, then I delete them in a batch.  This provides the same time complexities as `ArrayDeque`.